# Does checkinstall command add dependencies in the package?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-installer, source-code, checkinstall

I learned about [checkinstall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CheckInstall) today. I installed [mdp](https://github.com/visit1985/mdp) on Linux Lite installed on [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) using `checkinstall`.

`mdp` depends on a package called `libncursesw5-dev`, which wasn't installed on my machine. But when I ran `checkinstall`, `mdp` was installed and worked flawlessly.

So, here's what I need to know from you, does `checkinstall` install the dependencies and pack it in the .deb, .rpm, etc. files?

> **NOTE:** And yes, since I'm using Linux Lite on VirtualBox, I took a snapshot of the machine and used `make` instead of `checkinstall`, and `make` threw an error to install the dependencies first.

Answer (score 1):

`checkinstall` can't handle the dependencies to build the package automatically.

Dependencies need to be installed before executing `checkinstall`.

`mdp` depend on `libncurses5-dev`. `libncurses5-dev` should be installed on your system.

Only on raspbian `mdp` depend on `libncurses5-dev` and `libncursesw5-dev`.